# parse the html using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to get only the parse value of the html field here's my html.

```
 <tr valign="baseline">
   <td nowrap align="left"><label>data:</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="data" id="data" size="32" value=""></td>
   </tr>
```

and here's my jquery inside onclick function.

```
data =$("#try").html();

  $("#data").val(data);

            console.log("error");
```

and here's the result that display in the field

```
<p class="1">1</p><p class="2">2</p><p class="3">3</p>
```

i want to get only the value of P. its like 123 using php hope anyone can help me as soon as possible. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your description is a little confusing.
But if I got it right you end up with a string like

```
<p class="1">1</p><p class="2">2</p><p class="3">3</p>
```

And you have to filter that string in PHP, not in JS.

If so, just use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php)

```
echo strip_tags('<p class="1">1</p><p class="2">2</p><p class="3">3</p>');
```

Hope that is what you are looking for

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: i get this value <p class="1">1</p><p class="2">2</p><p class="3">3</p> when clicking the row in datatable and it's the id of the selected item. another question how can i get the whole value of selected row in getting only the id and send it to another table in database. hope my question is clear.

Comment: well, I am afraid, it isnt. First of all: I do not get why you have to parse anything in PHP. Actually I do not even get what you are trying to do here at all. And Secondly: Without a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, its going to be a challenge to help you

Comment: sorry for being confusing, my friend told me that the solution to my problem is to parse it first because when i getting the id it has a html tag. i really want is to get the value of selected row and send it to another table in database. and i think it's possible but i really need help because im trapped. hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) instead of [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)

```js
var data = $("#try p").text();

$("#data").val(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="left">
      <label>data:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="data" id="data" size="32" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="try">
  <p class="1">1</p>
  <p class="2">2</p>
  <p class="3">3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it works. thankyou for your fast response Mr. Arun :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to get the value of the text input without p tags 
you can do it using jquery by following jquery script

```
    data = $("#data").val();
```

```
alert($(data).text());
</pre>
```

or by PHP using 
    
    $data = $_GET ['data'];
    echo strip_tags($data);

Comment: atleast give an explanation about your answer